# Sharing of Records with other users in CosmosDB

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-cosmosdb

CosmosDB says you can use a Token broker app to handle authentication for mobile users which makes the need for a server based middle layer app go away.    Since this is new, I haven’t found much documentation on advanced sharing and security.

Example:

I have a mobile Xamarin Forms library app that has both Students, Teachers and Books.

Students can see their own books they have checked out.  And they can share what books they have checked out with select other students.

So, if Student Stan shares his checked-out books with Student Susie, then Susie can see what books Stan has checked out.

How can I handle this CosmosDB?   I know how to do this with a regular sql database by creating master / detail relationships.   Can I do the same with cosmos DB by creating master / detail json documents?

Comment: Are you asking 2 questions in 1, or do you mean to solve the 2nd part with 1st part?

Comment: I edited it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if you’d like to build a Token broker app to authenticate users and issue short-lived tokens to signed-in users, please refer to [Resource Token Broker on GitHub](https://github.com/kirillg/azure-documentdb-dotnet/tree/master/samples/xamarin/UserItems).

Secondly, for the books sharing functionality. If you model your data to keep `student-books-sharingrelations` in same document, which would provide an easy way for read almost all relation information in a query/request. Besides, as you mentioned, if you store these info/data in separate documents, which may need to make multiple queries/requests to get relation information.

This thread discussed about ‘’[How to create and update a relation between documents in DocumentDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997490/how-to-create-and-update-a-relation-between-documents-in-documentdb-using-asp-ne)”, which might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you Fred!   This was a HUGE help!